# What's the advantage of PAM modulation over QAM?

Tags: ethernet, modulation

What are the main advantages of PAM (Pulse amplitude modulation) modulation over QAM ?

Ethernet is using PAM for 1000BASET and 10GBASET, but any other high speed links use QAM like DOCSIS, ADSL/VDSL or any RF transport.

Comment: IIRC, the "BASE" in 1000BASE-T stands for baseband; meaning there's no rf carrier whose phase we could modulate to produce QAM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The big advantages of PAM are (1) that the receiver does not have to estimate phase to recover the data, which makes implementation far easier and (2) the transmitter does not have to be as high performance (in terms of phase noise and AM to PM nonlinearity).